# Which WYIWYG editor compatible with mat-form-field?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ckeditor, angular-forms

I am creating a mat-form-field that is a WYSIWYG editor.

I have tried the ckeditor and angular editor both of them are prompt the following error message:

```
Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
```

Is there any WYSIWYG editor that can compatible with mat-form-field?

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jcyhb) for your reference.

Comment: what does  <angular-editor ></angular-editor> this selector has

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you say?
Would you elaborate more?

Comment: mat-form-field mostly required input field

Comment: what are you doing in angular-editor?

Comment: I want the <angular-editor ></angular-editor> is the input field.

Comment: share proper code in stack blitz

Comment: I want the user can edit the content of this field in WYSIWYG mode.

Comment: check https://itnext.io/creating-a-custom-form-field-control-compatible-with-reactive-forms-and-angular-material-cf195905b451 and https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control. in brief, you need implements MatFormFieldControl<any>

Answer (score 0):

I used [ngx-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-editor) for my project, works fine.

And i had no problem using it along with angular-material

[image]